# Проблема с Django на Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: python, django, apache

Делал сайт на своей винде в PyCharm. Все было хорошо, но теперь проект готов и настало время грузить на мой VPS (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). Через исходник установил python3.6 (как на винде), потом создал виртуальное окружение (с python3.6) и настроил apache2, все делал по офф. документации, но почему-то у меня все равно используется стандартный python. Я понял это по следующей ошибке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой apache2.conf:

```
WSGIPythonPath /home/django_user/web-django/website:/home/django_user/./env/website_env:/home/django_user/./env/website_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages

<VirtualHost 5.187.2.153:8080>

    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    ServerAdmin info@website.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django_user/web-django/website/website/app.wsgi

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

app.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys
import site

#import django.core.handlers.wsgi
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'website.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/django_user/env/website_env/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Как мне запустить мой сайт через мое виртуальное окружение с python3.6?**

Comment: apahce2_mod_wsgi лучше не использовать, лучше поднимите сервер с помощью gunicorn или uwsgi и проксируйте на него запросы с апача (а лучше с nginx)

Comment: mod_wsgi тоже должен быть для Py3. Пакет libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 устарел и необходимо установить из исходников. 
Подробнее: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html Для сборки и компиляции необходим пакет apache2-dev

Comment: Свою проблему я решил с помощью этой стати: http://devmartin.com/blog/2015/02/how-to-deploy-a-python3-wsgi-application-with-apache2-and-debian/
Но задумался о переходе на gunicorn+nginx, так как гемороя (на первый взгляд) меньше и производительность выше
Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой при запуске Django 1.11 приложения с использованием Python 3.6, Apache2.4 и WSGI на Debian 8.

Проблема заключается в том, что `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py` должен использоваться с теми версиями `apache2` и `python`, под которые он был собран. В противном случае наблюдаются проблемы. У нас налицо проблема с импортом пакетов.

Обращаю внимание на то, что в инструкциях по настройке Django + Apache2 + WSGI часто пишут про `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py`, однако он используется **только для Python 2**, а для Python 3 должен использоваться `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` [см.How To Serve Django Applications with Apache and mod_wsgi on Ubuntu 16.04, Configure a Python Virtual Environment](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04):

- `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py` только для Python 2.7,
- `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` --- для Python 3,

иначе в stacktrace даже при правильно настроенном Python 3.6 виртуальном окружении будут возникать следы Python 2.7

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module'
```

При установке `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` он, если не ошибаюсь, заменит `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py` и сам добавиться в Apache2.

Но есть ещё один нюанс

> Проблема заключается в том, что `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py` должен использоваться с теми версиями `apache2` и `python`, под которые он был собран. В противном случае наблюдаются проблемы. У нас налицо проблема с импортом пакетов.

После установки `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`, `python3.6` окружение всё ещё не заработало, обнаружил `python3.5` в stacktrace

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module'
```

---

Удалось решить проблему двумя способами:

1. смириться и использовать самую свежую версию `python3`, которая доступна в стабильных репозиториях ОС;
2. самому собрать `mod-wsgi` для `python3.6`.

**1. Свежайший Python 3 из стабильного репозитория**

Для него в репозитории также должен быть собранный `mod_wsgi`

Ниже пример Python 3 в моей ситуации, версия может отличаться

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python3 python3-venv

# check python3 version
python3 -V
# >>> Python 3.5.4 is for my Debian 8 in September 2017

# setting virtual environment for WSGI
python3 -m venv /home/django_user/./env/website_env
source /home/django_user/./env/website_env/bin/activate
# check venv and get path for WSGI
(pyvenv_354) python -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'
# >>> /home/django_user/./env/website_env

# mod_wsgi from repo must be compatible
apt install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Теперь созданное виртуальное окружение `python3.5` можно вписать в конфиг `apache2`

```
<VirtualHost 5.187.2.153:8080>

    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    ServerAdmin info@website.com

    Define WWW_ROOT /home/django_user/web-django/website/website
    WSGIScriptAlias / ${MAIN_APP_PATH}/app.wsgi

    Define PYTHON_VENV_HOME /home/django_user/./env/website_env
    Define PYTHON_VENV_PACKAGES ${PYTHON_VENV_HOME}/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    WSGIDaemonProcess website processes=2 python-path=${WWW_ROOT}:${PYTHON_VENV_PACKAGES}
    WSGIProcessGroup website

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Теперь перезапустить Apache2 любым способом, я использую

```
service apache2 restart
```

**2. Собрать `mod_wsgi` для Python 3.6**

Сделано, опираясь на [mod_wsgi quick installation guide](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html#quick-installation-guide), большое спасибо @m9_psy за ссылку, очень выручил.

```
apt-get install python3.6 python3.6-dev apache2-dev
# checking Python version
python3.6 -V
# >>> 3.6.2

# set virtual environment
python3.6 -m venv /home/django_user/./env/website_env

# download mod_wsgi sources from https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases
# x, y, z --- version, select using link above
cd /usr/src/
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/x.y.z.tar.gz
tar xvfz x.y.z.tar.gz
cd mod_wsgi-x.y.z

# set python3.6 venv for mod_wsgi
./configure --with-python=/home/django_user/./env/website_env/bin/python

make
make install

# >>> Libraries have been installed in:
#   /usr/lib/apache2/modules
#   mod_wsgi.so

# adding module to apache2
cat /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load
nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
add to httpd.conf line `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so`
```

Теперь виртуальное окружение с `python3.6` может использоваться в `apache2`

```
<VirtualHost 5.187.2.153:8080>

    ServerName website.com
    ServerAlias www.website.com
    ServerAdmin info@website.com

    Define WWW_ROOT /home/django_user/web-django/website/website
    WSGIScriptAlias / ${MAIN_APP_PATH}/app.wsgi

    Define PYTHON_VENV_HOME /home/django_user/./env/website_env
    Define PYTHON_VENV_PACKAGES ${PYTHON_VENV_HOME}/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIDaemonProcess website processes=2 python-path=${WWW_ROOT}:${PYTHON_VENV_PACKAGES}
    WSGIProcessGroup website

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/website.com.error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

В завершении перезапустить `apache2`

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

На юниксов, чтобы  работать через виртуальное окружение надо установить virtualenv

```
pip3 install virtualenv  //Устанавливаем через pip третьего питона

virtualenv myenv //Создаём окружение
source myenv/bin/activate //Активируем его.
```

и дальше уже работаем в виртуальном окружении. Туда всё и ставим.